# Exceeding spreadsheets service usage

Tags: google-apps-script

I've suddenly started getting this error in my spreadsheet:

> Service invoked too many times in a short time: spreadsheets.

This pops up when I run a script function by hand, or sometimes in a custom function output (causing the cell's value to be #ERROR!).

My sheet has perhaps 100 (probably fewer) entries using a custom function like =bug(1050505). This custom function reads the values from one of the sheets in my spreadsheet and copies certain values from the row with the corresponding bug number. I admit this isn't terribly efficient, and I'd love to find a better way to do it. But it did always use to work. Have the limits on the spreadsheet service been lowered significantly? What can I do?

Comment: I just started getting the same thing tonight as well.

Comment: Try not using custom functions. Write regular code that runs `onEdit`, `onOpen` or on demand via a custom menu.

Comment: Can you share the code for the custom function `bug` - that might be helpful to see whats happening there.

Comment: I've got this problem too.  It seems to trigger as soon as I invoke a method on a Spreadsheet object.  When I run it from the code editor it runs fine.

My code to trigger:

`function master_payment_record(target_year,income_range) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log("here we go");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
return "yay";
}`

Comment: Are you still running into this?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it may not be just function calls that cause you to hit the quota limit. If you head over to [Google Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard) and click on `Quota Limits`, you will see limits such as:

- Email Recipients: **500 / day**
- SOAP calls: **500 / day**
- Triggers per script per user: **20 / day**
- UrlFetch Headers: **100**

A possible solution is to make your function to be invoked interactively, instead of it running automatically.